# Output of Unit Tests running in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

What I am trying to achieve is quite simple but I am probably missing something.
All I want is to INSTATNLY see my tests logging in the Console window, I have tried

```
Console.WriteLine(...)
```

I have tried

```
Trace.WriteLine(...)
```

I have tried

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
Trace.WriteLine(...)
```

This all show the output only AFTER the test has finished (and not in the Output console but as the "test output"), what I want is to see those logging as they happen.
The way I am running the tests is using "Test-> Run-> All Tests" from the VS main menu.

The only way I can somewhat achieve what I want is by using

```
Debug.WriteLine(...)
```

But for this I have to run the tests in debug "Test -> Debug -> All Tests" and its kinda annoying...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it make difference to you if you run your test via Visual Studio or MSTest? Through MSTest command line it can be done.

Comment: I am not familiar with MSTest, is there a quick access from within VS? This is a small personal project so I am looking for something easy & simple (like clicking on a button :)).

Comment: No, there is no access from Visual Studio. You can run it from command line. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Nahhh, too complicated compared to the ease of doing it in Visual Studio. Too bad they are not flushing the output to the output window, weird actually...

Comment: running into the same thing  - odd that it doesn't collect this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve this except the one which you already know. MSTest adapter keeps caching the trace output and once test finishes, it emits it in the test output window.

This is a useful ask and I will pass this request to the mstest product owner in visual studio team.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).